# Marking a message as seen

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, data-modeling

I am making a notification system with the following scenario.

A user from `company A` wants to send a message to all users(4000+) of `company B`. Everyone from `company B` receive the message in their inbox.

I am having trouble with designing efficient database design that will let me mark the message as "seen" when a user from `company B` clicks the message so that it is marked with different color in the user's inbox next time while others who have not seen it yet will get unread color.

My naive approach now is having a table where I have `messageId`, `userId` and `isSeen(bool)` column in `SQL Server` where I update the `isSeen` column to `true` when a user clicked a message with an ID.

The problem: I do not want to insert 4k rows into the table just for a message because it would have been a very inefficient and will drag down the performance of the database.

What can I do in my database design that will let me achieve the outcome I want and at the same time will not severe my database performance? Are `SQL databases` the right tools for this kind of task?

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe, is, in fact, the best way to do what you want.

If your table is indexed properly, the performance will not be bad at all.

Comment: The current solution would definitely drag down the performance because we have some companies with 10k users. Imaging 10 users from company A sending 10 messages each to comapny B...

Comment: It probably won't be as bad as you think.  And there isn't any faster way to do what you want.   The only faster option is to not do it.